# fetching from two mongo collection and storing another

Tags: java, mongodb

i have two collection

A

```
longitue latitude value
 78.2323  23.3242  34
 81.2344  23.255   45
```

B

```
 longitude latitude value
     78.2323   23.3242  76
     81.2344  23.255    49
```

output collection should be like C

```
 longitude latitude value
 78.2323   23.3242  110
 81.2344  23.255    94
```

each collection have 20 million records

by using java it takes too much time and some time its stops in between

i want to know does there is any fast way that we can create output collection  using mongo shell

Comment: You can check https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/, but afaik it doesn't work with compound keys. I'd go with  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/. It is quite slow, but at least it outputs directly into collection and does not stop in between.

Comment: If you run java application on same server and with reasonable settings like batch() with large value in it, your application should get and sum in couple of minutes. Then the most consuming part - insert 20 mln records. You can hope for 4-5 minutes. I doubt that aggregation framework will speed something. Do you really need results in another mongo collection?